# Android Assist service multi-touch was onCancelled

Tags: android, gesture, accessibilityservice

My scenario is remote control screen, using the API is `AccessibilityService.dispatchGesture`, the common click, swipe, multi-touch pressed at the same time are no problem.

But if the multi-touch interval is pressed, the onCancelled callback will be received. `GestureDescription.Builder.addStroke` to add multiple strokes,

I tried to add only one of them and found that each stroke can be dispatched normally, but when put together, it will fail to execute